# How to call this function with CYGWIN

Tags: cygwin

On Windows with Cygwin in the .bashrc file there is a function that you can uncomment.  I did so but I cannot figure out how to make it work or call it.

I tried doin the `cd --` in the command line but it doesn't do anything

```
# b) function cd_func
# This function defines a 'cd' replacement function capable of keeping, 
# displaying and accessing history of visited directories, up to 10 entries.
# To use it, uncomment it, source this file and try 'cd --'.
# acd_func 1.0.5, 10-nov-2004
# Petar Marinov, http:/geocities.com/h2428, this is public domain
 cd_func ()
 {
   local x2 the_new_dir adir index
   local -i cnt

   if [[ $1 ==  "--" ]]; then
     dirs -v
     return 0
   fi

   the_new_dir=$1
   [[ -z $1 ]] && the_new_dir=$HOME

   if [[ ${the_new_dir:0:1} == '-' ]]; then
     #
     # Extract dir N from dirs
     index=${the_new_dir:1}
     [[ -z $index ]] && index=1
     adir=$(dirs +$index)
     [[ -z $adir ]] && return 1
     the_new_dir=$adircd 
   fi

   #
   # '~' has to be substituted by ${HOME}
   [[ ${the_new_dir:0:1} == '~' ]] && the_new_dir="${HOME}${the_new_dir:1}"

   #
   # Now change to the new dir and add to the top of the stack
   pushd "${the_new_dir}" > /dev/null
   [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && return 1
   the_new_dir=$(pwd)

   #
   # Trim down everything beyond 11th entry
   popd -n +11 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null

   #
   # Remove any other occurence of this dir, skipping the top of the stack
   for ((cnt=1; cnt <= 10; cnt++)); do
     x2=$(dirs +${cnt} 2>/dev/null)
     [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && return 0
     [[ ${x2:0:1} == '~' ]] && x2="${HOME}${x2:1}"
     if [[ "${x2}" == "${the_new_dir}" ]]; then
       popd -n +$cnt 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
       cnt=cnt-1
     fi
   done

   return 0
 }
```

Comment: Have you  opened a new Cygwin shell/terminal, or `.` sourced the `.bashrc` file to get the function into your session?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "sourced" I thought that file was included already.  I just tried `source .bashrc` and it says `bash: $'\r': command not found`

Comment: Problem with DOS-like line endings, sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
alias cd="cd_func"
cd --
```

or simply

```
cd_func --
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking but it give this error `bash: cd_func: command not found`

Comment: Please note that .bashrc is NOT run (nor sourced) on login, this is when .bash_profile is applied instead. Usually .bash_profile should call 'source .bashrc' explicitly.

Comment: Ok thanks, now looking at my .bash_profile it looks like it comes with `source "${HOME}/.bashrc"`  already in it, thanks for your help